# Run JavaScript function when attempted to go to HTML anchor

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

Regardless of whether I'm trying to go to **index.html#ExistingAnchor** or **index.html#NotExistingAnchor** or any other anchor which might or might not exist on the page I'd like some javascript function to be run.

```
<html>
<body>
    <a name="ExistingAnchor"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

What javascript code can I use to achieve it?

The page may already be loaded so I'd be just visiting HTML anchors on the same page from the browser address bar without reloading the page.

Also, having visited a number of anchors on the same page when I'm using the Back and Forward browser history buttons, I'd like some JavaScript function to be run as well so that I could identify what anchor I'm currently on - could you please advise this as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On modern browsers you can implement onHashChange event, on IE6/7 you're going to need to use some trickery involving iFrames and window.setTimeout.

The jQuery history plugin will achieve what you want if you use jQuery, if not you can study it and port it for your needs.
http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/

Comment: `onHashChange` works great, thanks!

I'm not too good with JavaScript and I'm not using jQuery so I hope someone will also provide an answer on how to get some JavaScript function run when using the Back and Forward browser history buttons on the same page without reloading it; but I'll see if I can understand how jQuery history plugin works.

Comment: You're entering territory that requires quite a bit of javascript knowledge. I ported the history plugin to prototype for the website I work for and it was a minor nightmare getting back/forward buttons to work. I assume you're trying to get an interface similar to twitter/gawker up and running?

Comment: I just want to make back/forward buttons work on an Ajax webpage: its content would be reloaded depending on the location hash. So basically I only need to catch back/forward events.

Comment: For every action you perform on the ajax page you will need to change the hash and then track the state in the hash change event and load the appropriate state when it fires. It's not very straight forward because this is a hack but unfortunately the only way to do this in ajax apps.